# Rules of operation

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to implement the following. But the first four lines are not implementing in my rules!!!

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Format[subs[body_, sub_]] := Subscript[body, sub]

Format[subsup[body_, sub_, sup_]] := Subsuperscript[body, sub, sup]

Format[ket[body_]] := 
 Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", body, "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]

Format[oneket[]] := 
 Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]
Format[zeroket[]] := 
 Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]

Format[onebra[]] := 
 Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}]

Format[zerobra[]] := 
 Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}]

In[2566]:= onebra[] . zeroket[] = 0

Out[2566]= 0

In[2567]:= zerobra[] . oneket[] = 0

Out[2567]= 0

In[2568]:= onebra[] . oneket[] = 1

Out[2568]= 1

In[2569]:= zerobra[] . zeroket[] = 1

Out[2569]= 1

In[2570]:= comrule[(a_ + b_) . c_] := a . c + b . c

In[2571]:= UH1 = (1/Sqrt[2])*comrule[(zeroket[] + oneket[]) . (zerobra[])]

Out[2571]= (Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] + 
 Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}])/Sqrt[2]



In[2572]:= UH2 = (1/Sqrt[2])*comrule[(zeroket[] - oneket[]) . (onebra[])]

Out[2572]= ((-Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]) . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] + 
 Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}])/Sqrt[2]

In[2573]:= UH = UH1 + UH2

Out[2573]= ((-Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]) . 
   Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] + 
  Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
   Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}])/Sqrt[2] + (
 Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
   Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] + 
  Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
   Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}])/Sqrt[2]

In[2574]:= comrule1[(((-a_) . b_ + c_. d_)/Sqrt[2] + (x_. l_ + m_. n_)/Sqrt[2]) . 
   g_] := (((-a) . (b . g) + c . (d . g))/
    Sqrt[2] + (x . (l . g) + m . (n . g))/Sqrt[2])

In[2575]:= ff = UH . zeroket[]

Out[2575]= (((-Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]) . 
     Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] + 
    Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
     Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}])/Sqrt[2] + (
   Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
     Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] + 
    Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
     Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}])/Sqrt[2]) . 
 Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]

In[2576]:= pu = comrule1[ff] // FullSimplify

Out[2576]= ((-Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}]) . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] + 
 1 . Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "1", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] + 
 1 . Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "1", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] + 
 1 . Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", "0", "\[LeftBracketingBar]"}] . 
  Row[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "0", "\[RightAngleBracket]"}])/Sqrt[2]
```

Comment: `onebra[] . zeroket[]`  works. But you can not write assignment like: `onebra[] . zeroket[] = 0`, this gives an error. But perhaps you mean an equation:  `onebra[] . zeroket[] == 0`